# JAVA SWING GUI: Code isnt producing the right output

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, converters

The code im working on is supposed to be a Java GUI Swing that allows a user to convent distance measurements from inches to centimeters or vice versa using a graphical user interface (GUI) resembling the image below. ruler.png

Here is my code below

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ConvertGUI extends JFrame
{
        
    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JLabel label3;
    private JLabel label4;
    JLabel cent;
    JLabel inch;
    
    private JTextField inches;
    private JTextField centimeters;

    private JButton INtoCMButton;
    private JButton CMtoINButton;
    
    public ConvertGUI()
    {
        
        super( "Measurement Converter Appliaction" );   
        setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("ruler.png"));
        
        label1 = new JLabel( icon );
        add( label1 );
        
        label2 = new JLabel( "metric converter" );
        add( label2 );
 
        label3 = new JLabel( "inches:" );
        add( label3 );
        
        label4 = new JLabel( "centimeters:" );
        add( label4 );
        
        centimeters = new JTextField( 10 );
        add( centimeters);
       
        inches = new JTextField( 10 );
        add( inches);
        
        INtoCMButton = new JButton( "Convert to CM" );
        add( INtoCMButton );
        INtoCMButton.addActionListener( new ButtonHandlerIN() );
        
        CMtoINButton = new JButton( "Convert to IN" );
        add( CMtoINButton );
        CMtoINButton.addActionListener( new ButtonHandlerCM() );
        
    }
    
    private class ButtonHandlerIN implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            double num = Double.parseDouble( inches.getText() );
            
            double centimeters = (num *2.54);
            String INtoCM_String= String.format("%.1f", centimeters) ;
            
            cent.setText(INtoCM_String );
        }
    }
    
        private class ButtonHandlerCM implements ActionListener
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                double num = Double.parseDouble( cent.getText() );
                String CMtoIN_String= String.format("%.1f", inch) ;
                double inch = (num /2.54);
                inches.setText( CMtoIN_String  );   
            }
        }
        
        
}
```

and here is the other source code file needed to run

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Prog9 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConvertGUI window = new ConvertGUI();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize( 250, 180 );
        window.setVisible(true);
      
    }
}
```

here is my output but then in the documentation on eclipse i keep getting all kinds of errors. i believe its because of floating points?

(My Output window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your JLabels "cent" and "inch" were never instantiated as a `new JLabel();` Secondly, in your `ButtonHandlerCM` you attempted to use `String.format()` on `double inch` which had not been declared yet. I fixed these things and cleaned up your code a little bit for the sake of conciseness.

ConvertGUI.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ConvertGUI extends JFrame
{

    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JLabel label3;
    private JLabel label4;
    JLabel cent = new JLabel();
    JLabel inch = new JLabel();

    private JTextField inches;
    private JTextField centimeters;

    private JButton INtoCMButton;
    private JButton CMtoINButton;

    public ConvertGUI()
    {

        super( "Measurement Converter Application" );
        setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("ruler.png"));

        label1 = new JLabel(icon);
        add( label1 );

        label2 = new JLabel( "metric converter" );
        add( label2 );

        label3 = new JLabel( "inches:" );
        add( label3 );

        label4 = new JLabel( "centimeters:" );
        add( label4 );

        centimeters = new JTextField( 10 );
        add( centimeters);

        inches = new JTextField( 10 );
        add( inches);

        INtoCMButton = new JButton( "Convert to CM" );
        INtoCMButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                double num = Double.parseDouble( inches.getText() );
                double centimeters = (num *2.54);
                String INtoCM_String = String.format("%.1f", centimeters) ;
                cent.setText(INtoCM_String);
            }
        });

        add( INtoCMButton );
        CMtoINButton = new JButton( "Convert to IN" );
        CMtoINButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                double num = Double.parseDouble( centimeters.getText() );
                double inch = (num /2.54);
                String CMtoIN_String= String.format("%.1f", inch) ;
                inches.setText( CMtoIN_String  );
            }
        });
        add( CMtoINButton );
    }
}
```

Prog9.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Prog9 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConvertGUI window = new ConvertGUI();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize( 250, 180 );
        window.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```